# A way to get an interface with sub-sub-sub-property removed in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Say I have

```
interface A {
    b: {
         c: {
              d: string;
              e: number;
         }
    }
}
```

I would like to get interface `A_no_E` which is the same interface as `A` but **without `A.b.c.e`**

```
interface A_no_E {
    b: {
         c: {
              d: string;
         }
    }
}
```

Is there a handy way of getting `A_no_E` via advanced types of TypeScript **without having to redeclare the whole thing prop-by-prop**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, I suppose you could declare your own `DeepOmit` [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) type function that walks down through a tuple of keys... something like this:

```
// Tail removes the first element from a tuple type
// so Tail<[string, number, boolean]> is [number, boolean]
type Tail<L extends any[]> =
  ((...l: L) => void) extends ((h: infer H, ...t: infer T) => void) ? T : never;


type DeepOmit<T, K extends Array<keyof any>> =
  K extends [] ? T : K extends [infer P] ? Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, P>> : {
    [P in keyof T]: P extends K[0] ? DeepOmit<T[P], Tail<K>> : T[P]
  }
```

And then you can do

```
type A_no_E = DeepOmit<A, ['b', 'c', 'e']>;
```

This, if you use IntelliSense, evaluates to the somewhat ugly-looking

```
type A_no_E = {
    b: {
        c: Pick<{
            d: string;
            e: number;
        }, "d">;
    };
}
```

Which is equivalent to what you want:

```
declare const a_no_e: A_no_E
a_no_e.b.c.d; // string
a_no_e.b.c.e; // error, property e does not exist
```

---

EDIT: alternate definition of `DeepOmit` which produces a less ugly IntelliSense:

```
type Tail<L extends any[]> =
  ((...l: L) => void) extends ((h: infer H, ...t: infer T) => void) ? T : never;
type DeepOmit<T, K extends Array<keyof any>, KT extends keyof T = Exclude<keyof T, K[0]>> =
  K extends [] ? T : K extends [infer P] ? { [Q in KT]: T[Q] } : {
    [P in keyof T]: P extends K[0] ? DeepOmit<T[P], Tail<K>> : T[P]
  }
```

Now `A_no_E` is shown in IntelliSense as:

```
type A_no_E = {
    b: {
        c: {
            d: string;
        };
    };
}
```

---

Hope that helps.

Comment: this looks like black magic to me, will take my time to study it

Comment: updated with alternative definition of `DeepOmit` which is itself uglier but yields nicer-looking output types.

Answer (score 0):

If you know precisely the path to omit I guess you could do this using an intersection type like in this [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20d%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atype%20NotE%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%3A%20never%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Atype%20AnotE%20%3D%20A%20%26%20NotE%3B%0A%0Avar%20a%3A%20A%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20c%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20d%3A%20%22string%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20e%3A%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20b%3A%20AnotE%20%3D%20a%3B). The idea is to intersect a type which does not accept a value at the specified path with the original type `A`.

Comment: it requires redeclaration, which i wish i could avoid (per what is said in the question) AND the example you posted doesn't typecheck

Comment: It doesn't typecheck to illustrate that both types are now incompatible thanks to the intersection type.

Comment: Well, this `var b: AnotE = { b: { c: { d: "string" } } }` won't work. And this is what OP asked

Comment: Totally right! I guess I found myself in what is described in the latest example https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html . My bad.

Comment: You should probably delete the answer :)